# In this code it sets false in err variable but after the $.post block it always return true... Is there any other way to solve this code

Tags: jquery

This function is called when I submit the page if the record exits I want page will not submit .. But it is not working..

```
   function checkvalidation(){

        var err=true;
        var party_id = $('#party_id').val();            
        var item_id = $('#item_id').val();
        var typ =$('#type').val();                  

        $.post("<?= base_url() ?>checkduplicate.php?item="+item_id+"&party="+party_id+"&type="+typ,function(r){
            if(r != "")
            {
                err = false;


            }
        });

        return err;
    }
```

Comment: this is because `$.post()` is async in nature.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var party_id = $('#party_id').val();            
var item_id = $('#item_id').val();
var typ =$('#type').val();  
var jqxhr = $.post( "<?= base_url() ?>checkduplicate.php?item="+item_id+"&party="+party_id+"&type="+typ, function() {
  alert( "success" );
})
  .done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
});
```

but when this function is called, it execute submit.
If you want to check the parameters you can try this

```
function checkParam(param){
 return typeof param != 'undefined' && param != null;
};
function checkvalidation(){
var party_id = $('#party_id').val();            
var item_id = $('#item_id').val();
var typ =$('#type').val();  

if(checkParam(party_id) && checkParam(item_id) && checkParam(typ)){
 var jqxhr = $.post( "<?= base_url() ?>checkduplicate.php?item="+item_id+"&party="+party_id+"&type="+typ, function() {
 alert( "success" );
})

}else{
 //code
 return;
}
```

}